# OpenSearch - AzureAD - SAML authentication. No roles available for this user, please contact your system administrator

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0, opensearch, idp

I am trying to setup SAML authentication between OpenSearch and AzureAD.

When trying to login to OpenSearch dashboard, I get this "No roles available for this user, please contact your system administrator."

Users are in a AD Group called "Admin".

What would be the correct Subject key / role key in this scenario?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error **"No roles available for this user, please contact your system administrator"** usually occurs when the roles are not mapped in **`SAML assertion`**.

These role mappings are **case-sensitive**. No roles means having no permissions. Please check the contents of your SAML assertion using [SAML-tracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) tool.

Though role attributes are optional, most IDPs can be configured to add roles in SAML assertion. You can add these roles in your role mappings like below:

```java
<saml2:Attribute Name='Role'>
<saml2:AttributeValue >Everyone</saml2:AttributeValue>
<saml2:AttributeValue >Admins</saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

To check your role mappings, make use of below query:

```
GET _plugins/_security/api/rolesmapping
```

To extract roles from the SAML response, you need to specify the element name that contains the roles.

**Subject Key**

> The attribute in the SAML response where the **subject** is stored.
> This is Optional. If it is not configured, the `NameID` attribute of the SAML
> assertion for the username is used.

Leave Subject key field empty or include username as custom attribute by specifying it.

**Roles Key**

> The attribute in the SAML response where the **roles** are stored. This is
> Optional. If it is not configured, no roles are used.

Add `Optional SAML settings - Roles key` value as

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups
```

For more in detail, please **refer** these links: [Ref1](https://The%20error%20**%22No%20roles%20available%20for%20this%20user,%20please%20contact%20your%20system%20administrator%22**%20usually%20occurs%20when%20the%20roles%20are%20not%20mapped%20in%20SAML%20assertion%20even%20if%20you%20authenticated%20successfully.%20These%20role%20mapping%20are%20case-sensitive.%20No%20roles%20mean%20having%20no%20permissions.%20Please%20check%20the%20contents%20of%20your%20SAML%20assertion%20using%20%5BSAML-tracer%5D(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/)%20tool.%20%20%20%20Though%20role%20attributes%20are%20optional,%20most%20IDPs%20can%20be%20configured%20to%20add%20roles%20in%20SAML%20assertion.%20You%20can%20add%20these%20roles%20in%20your%20role%20mappings%20like%20below:%20%60%60%60java%20%3Csaml2:Attribute%20Name=%27Role%27%3E%20%3Csaml2:AttributeValue%20%3EEveryone%3C/saml2:AttributeValue%3E%20%3Csaml2:AttributeValue%20%3EAdmins%3C/saml2:AttributeValue%3E%20%3C/saml2:Attribute%3E%20%60%60%60%20To%20check%20your%20role%20mapping,%20make%20use%20of%20below%20query:%20%20%20%20GET%20_plugins/_security/api/rolesmapping%20%20%20%20To%20extract%20roles%20from%20the%20SAML%20response,%20you%20need%20to%20specify%20the%20element%20name%20that%20contains%20the%20roles.%20%20%20%20%20**Subject%20Key**%20%20%20%20The%20attribute%20in%20the%20SAML%20response%20where%20the%20subject%20is%20stored.%20Optional.%20If%20not%20configured,%20the%20%60NameID%60%20attribute%20of%20the%20SAML%20assertion%20for%20the%20username%20is%20used.%20%20%20%20Leave%20Subject%20key%20field%20empty%20or%20include%20username%20as%20custom%20attribute%20by%20specifying%20it%20%20%20%20**Roles%20Key**%20%20%20%20The%20attribute%20in%20the%20SAML%20response%20where%20the%20roles%20are%20stored.%20Optional.%20If%20not%20configured,%20no%20roles%20are%20used.%20%20%20%20To%20add%20%E2%80%9COptional%20SAML%20settings%20-%20Roles%20key%E2%80%9D%20value%20as%20%20%20%20http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups%20%20%20%20For%20more%20in%20detail,%20please%20refer%20below%20links:%20%20%20%20%5Bamazon-opensearch-service-developer-guide/saml.md%20at%20master%20%C2%B7%20awsdocs/amazon-opensearch-service-developer-guide%20%C2%B7%20GitHub%5D(https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-opensearch-service-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/saml.md).%20%20%20%20%5BHow%20to:%20login%20into%20Kibana/AWS%20OpenSearch%20using%20Azure%20AD%20-%20Haufe-Lexware.github.io%20(haufegroup.io)%5D(http://work.haufegroup.io/aws-opensearch-kibana-azure-ad/).%20%20%20%20%5BSAML%20-%20OpenSearch%20documentation%5D(https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/configuration/saml/#opensearch-dashboards-settings).), [Ref2](http://work.haufegroup.io/aws-opensearch-kibana-azure-ad/), [Ref3](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/configuration/saml/#opensearch-dashboards-settings)